# what is the time complexity for copying list back to arrays and vice-versa in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, copy

I am wondering what is the time complexity [in big `O(n)` notations] of  `ArrayList` to `Array` conversion:

```
ArrayList assetTradingList = new ArrayList();
assetTradingList.add("Stocks trading");
assetTradingList.add("futures and option trading");
assetTradingList.add("electronic trading");
assetTradingList.add("forex trading");
assetTradingList.add("gold trading");
assetTradingList.add("fixed income bond trading");
String [] assetTradingArray = new String[assetTradingList.size()];
assetTradingArray.toArray(assetTradingArray);
```

similarly, what is the time complexity for arrays to list in the following ways:

method 1 using `Arrays.asList`:

```
String[] asset = {"equity", "stocks", "gold", "foreign exchange","fixed
    income", "futures", "options"};
List assetList = Arrays.asList(asset);
```

method 2 using `collections.addAll`:

```
    List assetList = new ArrayList();
    String[] asset = {"equity", "stocks", "gold", "foreign exchange", "fixed
        income", "futures", "options"};
    Collections.addAll(assetList, asset);
```

method 3 `addAll`:

```
     ArrayList newAssetList = new ArrayList();
     newAssetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(asset));
```

The reason I am interested in the overhead of copying back and forth is because in typical interviews, questions come such as `given an array of pre-order traversal elements, convert to binary search tree` and so on, involving `arrays`. With `List` offering a whole bunch of operations such as `remove` etc, it would make it simple to code using `List` than `Array`.

In which case, I would like to defend me for using `list` instead of `arrays` saying "I would first convert the Array to List because the overhead of this operation is not much (hopefully)".

Any better methods recommended for copying the elements back and forth from `array to list` that would be faster would be good know too.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the source code?

Comment: Take a loot at the implementations of each. They are available on the interwebs. Hint: If you want a copy, you need to copy every reference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I understand copying references. I am interested in any methods which the community recommend.

Answer (score 15):

It would seem that `Arrays.asList(T[]);` is the fastest with`O(1)`

Because the method returns an unmodifiable `List`, there is no reason to copy the references over to a new data structure. The method simply uses the given array as a backing array for the unmodifiable `List` implementation that it returns.

The other methods seem like they copy each element, one by one to an underlying data structure. `ArrayList#toArray(..)` uses `System.arraycopy(..)` deep down (`O(n)` but faster because it's done natively). `Collections.addAll(..)` loops through the array elements (`O(n)`).

---

Careful when using `ArrayList`. The backing array doubles in size when its capacity is reached, ie. when it's full. This takes `O(n)` time. Adding to an `ArrayList` might not be the best idea unless you know how many elements you are adding from the beginning and create it with that size.

Comment: is there a similar `O(1)` method that would convert  `List` to `Array`?

Comment: @user1988876 It depends on the implementation. I can't think of one right now. Typically, the `toArray()` method should not return the same underlying structure (if it was an array) that the `List` uses.

Comment: but I suppose ArrayList is the only other alternative if I want to have dynamic size? with Arrays size is pre-defined when we construct them correct?

Comment: @user1988876 Arrays are static, yes. You cannot change their size after they've been created. `ArrayList` are dynamically sized, but to achieve that, they need to create a new, bigger, array and copy over the elements when the previous one can't hold the next new element. Alternatively, adding to a `LinkedList` is `O(1)`, but it has other drawbacks, ex. element lookup. Use the implementation that fits your use case best.

Comment: @user1988876: Resizing an ArrayList is O(n).  That defeats the purpose of worrying about construction efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Since the backing data structure of `ArrayList` is an array, and copying of an array elements is a O(n), it is O(n).

The only overhead I see is pollution of heap with those intermediate objects. Most of the time developers (especially, beginners) don't care about that and treat Java GC as a magic wand that cleans everything after them. My personal opinion is, if you can avoid unwanted transformation of array to list and vice versa, do that.

If you know beforehand the foreseeable (e.g. defined) size of a list, preallocate its size with `ArrayList(int size)` constructor to avoid internal array copying that takes place inside `ArrayList` when capacity is exhausted. Depending on a use case, consider other implementations, e.g. `LinkedList`, if you're only interested in consequent addition to the list, and iterative reading.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is fundamentally just a wrapper around an `Object[]` array. It has a lot of helpful methods for doing things like finding items, adding and removing items, and so on, but from a time complexity perspective these are no better than doing the operations yourself on a plain array.

If your hope is that an `ArrayList` is fundamentally more efficient than a manually managed array, it's not. Sorry!

- Converting an array to an `ArrayList` takes O(*n*) time. Every element must be copied.
- Inserting or removing an element takes O(*m*) amortized time, where *m* is the number of elements following the insertion/removal index. These elements have to be moved to new indices whether you use an array or `ArrayList`.

  "Amortized" means average -- sometimes the backing array will need to be grown or shrunk, which takes additional time on the order of O(*n*). This doesn't happen every time, so on the whole the additional time averages out to an O(1) additional cost.
- Accessing an element at an arbitrary index takes O(1) time. Both provide constant time random access.